# Clipping a raster from quickmapservices or XYZ tiles

Tags: qgis, xyz

I'm trying to clip a google satellite XYZ tile over a layer mask of my DEM layer[image: Settings im using to export the XYZ layer as a tif] to make a 3D map. 
the problem is that after making the connection and adding it as a layer to my project, im unable to save it as a geotiff. It keeps returning an error saying "data source "filename.tif" is an invalid data source.

Moreover, I've noticed another issue, if i uncheck the vrt option while trying to export> save as geotiff, the file does not get saved at all!

Answer (score 2):

Don't just enter a file name where it says "file name." You have to provide an entire file path. The easiest way to do this is to click the `...` button and choose the file you want to save to. Or type in the full file path and file name, eg, instead of "Google Satellite" enter "C:\Users\Documents\Google Satellite.tif."